# What is the main difference between SQL filter and correlation filter in Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

As explained in MSDN (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/topic-filters) SQL Filter and Correlation Filter both uses message's system defined and user defined properties.

Can you please provide an example to show the difference among both?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a [blog post](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/asb-subs-with-correlation-filters) where all three filter types are explained

1. Boolean filters
2. Correlation filters
3. SQL filters

There are several differences between correlation and SQL filters. Just to list a few

- Within a correlation filter, multiple conditions are AND-ed. SQL filter is much more flexible and can use AND as well as OR operations.
- The cost of evaluating filter expression is minimal and almost immediate w/o extra compute required. SQL filters can require more compute but offer more flexibility.

Comment: I think first bullet is invalid as docs say 
"""A CorrelationFilter holds a set of conditions that are matched against one or more of an arriving message's user and system properties."""

Comment: You're correct. Removed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

- A **SqlFilter** holds a SQL-like conditional expression "evaluated" in the broker against the arriving messages' user-defined properties and system properties.
- A **CorrelationFilter** holds a set of conditions that are "matched" against one or more of an arriving message's user and system properties.

So, for evaluation cases go for SQL Filter and the "match exists" case go for Correlation filter.